# mule filter in a sub flow is not stopping flow processing, continuing with main flow

Tags: mule

I used mule filter in a subflow but it is not stopping the complete process when the condition is false. It is exiting from subflow and continuing with mailflow. Actually it should exit from main flow as well. Please suggest how I stop complete process when filter condition is false.

Comment: Please review and amend: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you put filter in sub flow, it should stop processing entire flow and control will never comes back to main flow. Please find sample to check this.

Answer (score 0):

The flow does not know you have put a filter into a sub-flow.  It does not know details of the function of the sub-flow, rather, it sees it as a single step.  The sub-flow is called, it executes, it returns, and does not return any information saying you have included a filter and want the main flow to stop processing.

What you seem to be trying to do is set a signal in the sub-flow that tells the main flow if it should continue processing.  This can be done, but not automatically through a filter mechanism.  You could for instance use the filter in the sub-flow to set a value with session scope which the main flow would then look at and choose a processing route to accomplish the flow pattern you seem to be trying.

This is not the most elegant approach, there are many alternatives, but that is the first approach that comes to mind which closely approximates what you describe.